# Is there a way to figure out which channel the user is on Google TV player app?

Tags: java, android, google-tv

Is this possible with GTV 2.0? There used to be a permission VIEW_HISTORY that appears to no longer be accessible.

Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

> Is there a way to figure out which channel the user is on Google TV player app?

No, because the Google TV device has no way to know. It can *change* the channel, but if the device is a set-top box, the user could change the channel by other means, and the device has no way to know that.

Comment: What about 2-way Dish Set-top-box though? I heard developers attempt to go through Dish API to determine that. Where can I find that?